# KNIME batch mode execution hangs/never returns (started from Java process)

Tags: java, knime

I'm executing a KNIME workflow in [batch mode](https://tech.knime.org/faq#q12) from Java.

The output seems to indicate success, but the process never returns (I have to use a timeout parameter to kill it).

Question: Does anyone have an idea why the process never returns?

```
Executing [C:\Program Files\KNIME\KNIME.exe, -noexit, -nosplash, -nosave, -reset, -application, org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION, -workflowFile="C:\...\workflow.knwf", -workflow.variable=template.sdf,C:\...\template.sdf,String, --launcher.suppressErrors]  [main] at AntBuildLogger.messageLogged()
KNIME.exe stdout: CompilerOracle: exclude javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot                            [Thread-2] at AntBuildLogger.messageLogged()
KNIME.exe stdout: INFO   main BatchExecutor  ===== Executing workflow C:\...\workflow.knwf =====  [Thread-2] at AntBuildLogger.messageLogged()
...
KNIME.exe stdout: INFO   main BatchExecutor  Workflow execution done Finished in 3 secs (3937ms)             [Thread-2] at AntBuildLogger.messageLogged()
KNIME.exe stdout: INFO   main BatchExecutor  ============= Workflow executed sucessfully ===============     [Thread-2] at AntBuildLogger.messageLogged()
```

I'm using Windows 10 and KNIME 3.2.1.

I'm using the Ant Exec task programmatically, so I'm pretty confident that all the in/out/err [streams are handled correctly](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) (also I'm using that code to invoke many other executables).

Comment: Maybe without the `-noexit` parameter?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for spotting that! Please convert to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the [`-noexit`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html#osginoshutdown) parameter (it is useful on Windows when manually started) as it prevents closing the process after finishing the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Windows requires the `-consoleLog -noexit` to keep a DOS window open to see the console output.  Once you've tested the Knime batch run you can remove the `-consoleLog -noexit` parameters so it will not hang while waiting for the user to exit the process.

To see additional options you can run the following in a DOS window.
`knime.exe -consoleLog -noexit -nosplash -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION`